# How do I get google sheets to calculate multiple amounts if given a "group"

Tags: google-sheets

How do I get a value from `Column D` to calculate if `Column A` reads a specific group. Meaning If column A shows `groceries` then it reads Column D Amount and adds it to a running total in say `G3`. I have tried `Countif's` but that only works if I am counting the total number of catagories not the amount that was spent. I am having an issues with this and hoping someone can assist.

***Problem:***

[image]

Comment: Use: `=SUMIF(A2:A6,"Grocery",D2:D6)`  where A2:A6 is the list of types, `"Grocery"` should match the value, and `D2:D6` contains the values to be summed.    (of course you need to expand the `6` to the end of your list...)

Comment: Running total means, do you want sum of previous amounts each time item group change?